# Selecting a node's atomic value on typed xml columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, xpath

How can you get the atomic value of an element in a typed xml column if you can't use text() on it?

This query;

```
-- Add schema
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION MySchema AS N'<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            xmlns="http://mynamespace"
            targetNamespace="http://mynamespace">

  <xs:element name="element1" type="element1Type">
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="element1Type">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="element2" type="element2Type" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="element2Type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="element3" type="element3Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="element3Type">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="element4" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>'
GO

-- Create table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [XmlColumn] [xml](CONTENT [dbo].[MySchema]) NOT NULL
)
GO

-- Add test data
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT N'<element1 xmlns="http://mynamespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <element2>
    <element3>
      <element4>my text here</element4>
    </element3>
  </element2>
</element1>'
GO

-- run query
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
    'http://mynamespace' as s,
    DEFAULT 'http://mynamespace'
)
SELECT 
    T.rows.value('(element3/element4)[1]/text()', 'varchar(100)') as [AtomicValue]
FROM
    MyTable
CROSS APPLY
    XmlColumn.nodes('/element1/element2') T(rows)
```

Results in;

```
XQuery [MyTable.XmlColumn.value()]: 'text()' is not supported on simple typed or
'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyType' elements, found
'element({http://mynamespace}:element4,xs:anyType) ?'.
```

I've read [this](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/Fun-with-static-XQuery-evaluation-3.aspx), but mass-editing the schema on every atomic value I want to be able to read feels like overkill...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the schema you use and sample XML that shows the error.

Comment: Yeah it would be good to see the structure.

Comment: Instead of *text()* did you try to use the *item()* or maybe the *node()*?

Comment: @Mikael added full repro query

Comment: @András using node() returns the same exception.  I am not sure of the syntax for item()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `query` and then `value`.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
    'http://mynamespace' as s,
    DEFAULT 'http://mynamespace'
)
SELECT 
    T.rows.query('element3/element4').value('.', 'varchar(100)')
FROM
    MyTable
CROSS APPLY
    XmlColumn.nodes('/element1/element2') T(rows)
```

Or you can specify the type of `element4` in the schema.

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="element4" type="xs:string"/>
```

and use this query

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
    'http://mynamespace' as s,
    DEFAULT 'http://mynamespace'
)
SELECT 
    T.rows.value('(element3/element4)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as [AtomicValue]
FROM
    MyTable
CROSS APPLY
    XmlColumn.nodes('/element1/element2') T(rows)
```